# VBA Loop to go through table and export chart to each email

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

I need an excel file to email an exported chart to a varying number of contacts on open. For every email, the chart needs to be refiltered. I figured out how to do this by creating a dynamic chart with a scrollbar and on each iteration of the loop I will at 13 to its position (p).

How do I get my VBA code to send an email with the exported chart to whatever is in column 2? It also is currently only sending one email, rather than however many are in the column. Any help would be awesome.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim b1 As Workbook, b2 As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet

   Set b1 = ThisWorkbook

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim email As Range
    Dim book As Range

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set olMail = olApp.createitem(i)
    Set book = Range("A1:B9")
    p = 1

    'START LOOP
    For Each email In book.Rows
        Sheets("nothing").Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = p

        Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Activate
        ActiveChart.Export "testchartlocation.png"

        With olMail
            .To = "test@email.com"
            .Subject = "Emailer Testing..."
            .HTMLbody = "<html><p>Testing...</p><img src='testchartlocation.png'>"
            .display
        End With
        p = p + 13
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Next
    'END LOOP

    'ThisWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by

> How do I get my VBA code to send an email with the exported chart to
>   whatever is in column 2?

You mean you have email addresses stored in column 2 that you need to access with each iteration to send the exported chart to, you could change this line

```
.To = "test@email.com"
```

To

```
.To = Cells(email.Row, 2) '<-Make sure to qualify this range with whatever worksheet you're pulling from
```

Concerning your issue with your email only being generated once, you need to move

```
Set olMail = olApp.createitem(i) '<- you can change `i` to `0`
```

Into the beginning of your `For-Next` loop and set it = `Nothing` at the end like

```
For Each email In book.Rows
    Set olMail = olApp.createitem(0)
    'Do Stuff
    Set olMail = Nothing
Next email
```

That way a new email is generated every iteration.

**EDIT:**

You can probably get rid of this line

```
Sheets("nothing").Range("B1").Select
```

And replace

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = p
```

With

```
Sheets("nothing").Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = p
```

Since you're working with multiple sheets and `.Activate` functions, I would recommend qualifying **all** of your ranges.

Comment: Happy I could help!